# .NET code access security - why is it hardly ever used?

Tags: .net, security

.NET [code access security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737995/what-is-code-access-security-in-net) has been around for a long time, yet it seems to hardly ever be used in the real world.

To my way of thinking, this seems like an excellent concept, and one I had not seen prior to .NET. (Does it exist in other languages?)

I would like to know if anyone is proactively using it in their projects and why?

For those not using it, are there valid reasons beyond "we don't have a budget for security" or "I don't have the time to learn security"?

Finaly how effective is it at achieving it's goals?

Comment: Good question. I would agree (from my experience) that it's scarcely used at all, but couldn't say why. The learning curve is certainly a factor however. Perhaps most developers have just never found a use for it? I certainly haven't over my number of years developing in VB.NET and C#...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real reason is that Microsoft gave no guidance and best practices on how to use code access security.  So it never really took off.  They never explained why you would want to protect your code.  What happens when an exception occurs, how is it recovered from.  I think those are the main problems.

Don't confuse this with data access security which has been giving guidance and best practices.

Comment: I'm not following why "what happens when an exception occurs" has anything to do with CAS -- were you thinking of the ReliabilityContract stuff?

Comment: No an exception is thrown when you don't have access to some code.  What happens when you code relies on that block of code?  How do you handle that situation?

Answer (score 8):

It isn't used much because for an end-developer (ie. not a developer that builds components for other developers to use), most of the time, we're targeting a full-trust environment, or targeting such an environment is an option.  Either the code will run on our webserver, or on client machines owned by our company.  In either case, running code at full-trust isn't an issue -- the entity the code runs as trusts the developer.  The only case I know of where CAS is used is in an environment like Sharepoint, and half the time, we just GAC those assemblies for full-trust anyway.

So why don't we expend the effort to learn how to write our code for a partially-trusted scenario?  Well, to be honest, full-trust works, and if you're not in a scenario where the executer can't trust the writer, it's not needed, and my clients don't pay me for ivory-tower architecture -- they pay me for running code that meets their business needs.  In most common cases, CAS isn't required.

Comment: Are you saying that all the end user desktops run with administrative privliges in these companies?

Comment: No.  Full trust doesn't mean it runs as admin.  Full trust means it runs with the full privs of the user running it.

Comment: CAS is about protecting the user running the application from the application.  A full trust application running as a normal user can't do admin things.